# want to create a javascript function which on clicking button call php function which create a select option

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

1. following is the code with start button and its function which is not working but when im trying to echo hello in place of button tag then the function is working well

   ```
     <button onclick="startexam()" id="btn" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" title="Start 
      exam">Start Exam</button>
     <?php
     function php_func(){  
     echo  '<select class="form-select" aria-label="Default select example"><option > 
     asdf</option></select>'; 
     }

     ?>
      <script>
     //function called when user click on start exam button
     function startexam() {
     var result = "<?php php_func(); ?>"
     document.write(result);
     }
     </script>
   ```

Comment: You need to use AJAX for this, you can't call PHP functions directly from JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to understand what the technical difference between PHP and JavaScript is:

**JavaScript** executes scripts directly in your browser, e. g. Firefox. So, when JavaScript is executed, the page is already loaded.

**PHP** executes scripts on the server **before** the page is even in the browser.

So, if you want JavaScript to communicate with the server (the PHP script), you have to make a request to the server. To do so, use AJAX.

### How does AJAX work?

From [W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_ajax_intro.asp):

1. An event occurs in a web page (the page is loaded, a button is clicked)
2. An XMLHttpRequest object is created by JavaScript
3. The XMLHttpRequest object sends a request to a web server
4. The server processes the request
5. The server sends a response back to the web page
6. The response is read by JavaScript
7. Proper action (like page update) is performed by JavaScript

### How to use AJAX?

You can find a complete and clear introduction on [W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_ajax_intro.asp).